# Making Pumpkin Preserve

Tags: jam, pumpkin

I have ate the most wonderful pumpkin preserves (in chunks about 1-2 inches).  I have bought very small jars from Armenia and Russian stores in the US and the preserves were very expensive, but delicious.  Here is my problem.  I do not need a recipe as I have made good preserves of many fruits, whole and chunks, for over 35 years.  My problem with the pumpkin is should I take off the skin by peeling it and then cutting it, or, should I first cut it, clean the insides, quick boil it for a few minutes, then peel it and then continue on to preserve it?  It's a long process either way, but our hearts want it, so Mama gonna make it. HELP

Comment: Russian pumpkin preserves are generally made from roasted pumpkin.  You'll lose a bit of flavor by boiling.

Comment: Actually boiling does not really lose the flavor is done in the correct amount of water because after skimming of the "dirt" of the pumpkin, you use that water to make the syrup for the pumpkin.  Unfortunately, baking does something to the texture.  I still have to boil it in the syrup to get it nice and firm, not mushy.

Comment: you aren't losing flavor from the boiling your losing the flavors that you get from roasting.  Dry heat will impart different flavors to the food.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site recommends washing, slicing in half, removing seeds, slicing into 1 inch slices, peeling the skin, then chunking, and giving each chunk a brief boil for 2 minutes. Then going on to pressure can the product. It cannot be safely preserved with out pressure.

http://nchfp.uga.edu/tips/fall/pumpkins.html

And I hope you save the seeds and roast them! One of my favorite fall treats.

Comment: I read the link you have in your answer but disagree with what they say.  I have read other articles on "candied" pumpkin which is almost what I am doing and boiling is what I am doing along with many other people who have done this for ages and ages.  Thank you for thinking of our safety.

Comment: @ user33210, if you're planning on making small batches and eating the preserves right away (within a week or two), then you don't need to worry about pressure canning.  But (at least) in the US, pumpkin (of any kind) requires pressure canning to ensure it's safely preserved.